# PHP & Mysql prevent negative value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have develop an inventory system.

Apparently, some unknown (still figuring it out) reason, the deduction of stocks leads to a negative inventory count.

Users said this might happen if multiple users tries to dispense an inventory with only 1 count left.

I already forseen this but its still happening.

My function is something like this:

```
$request contains all item to be deducted, it has item_id and quantity
$employee is the user who will do the transaction

function applyInvoice($request, $employee) {

    ** gets all items and its current stock ** (basesd on the item_ids in the request)

    ** for each items **
       ** if current stock is less than the quantity to be deducted
              ** error: insufficient stock **
    ** end for each **

    ** if no errors **
       ** update quantity, deduct inventory **
    ** else **
       ** return error **

}
```

thats the application logic, still for unknown cases, it deducts to the quantity that leads to negative count.

Is the something wrong with my application logic? 
Does mysql by default provide locking for simultaneous update?

Comment: Yes, MySQL has a `FOR UPDATE` functionality which can lock a record for updating in a transaction, allowing you to read the same record afterward without other threads being able to mutate the data in that record.

Comment: Do you use transaction in applyInvoice method?

Comment: I am currently not using th e FOR update on my select, maybe this is the cause of it

Comment: @MaximFedorov yes I use transaction

Comment: @Roi you can get an explicit lock on the tables using `LOCK TABLES WRITE;` and then fetch the stock quantity ; subtract and update, and then dont forget to do `UNLOCK TABLES;`

Comment: please show your actual application code as opposed to the explanation. I suggest if you want to force a minimum 0 value, ensure you utilize transactions as well as set the column type to `UNSIGNED` which will ensure it is never negative.

Comment: @Roi, as said Tim Biegeleisen, you should use FOR UPDATE statement for locking simultaneous update